# How to solve this linear equation with three variables but two equations and asking value of third equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$2x + 5y + 8z = 100; 3x + 5y + 7z = 120; x + y + z = ?$
I have tried adding up and subtracting equations from each other which gives $x - z = 20$ and $x + 2y + 3z = 44$ but I still can't reach to $x + y + z$ form.

If we can come up with some inequality for $x + y + z$ like $x + y + z \ge 20$ then that is also acceptable.

Comment: Pretend that $z$ is a constant, and solve the first two equations for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $z$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What happens when you add $x−z=20$ and $x+2y+3z=44$? (Hoping they are correct)

Answer (score 1):

You know that $$x-z=20$$ which implies $$x=20+z$$ Now substitute this value in  $$x+2y+3z=44$$ It becomes $$20+2y+4z=44$$ which is $$2y+4z=24$$ therefore and that gives me $$y+2z=12$$ Now add $$x-z=20$$ with $$y+2z=12$$ you get $$x+y+z=32$$ your desired value

Answer (score 1):

If you do what William Stagner suggested, solving the first equations considering that $z$ is a constant, you get $$x=20+z$$ $$y=12-2z$$ Now express $x+y+z$ as a function of $z$ and enjoy the result.